# Is there a "windirstat"/"Disk Inventory X" type iOS app? (ie app for visualizing hard drive usage on iOS)

Tags: ios, hard-drive, ios-appstore, disk-space

This is a pretty simple question. Assuming you know what WinDirStat &/or Disc Inventory X do, which is visualize the usage of your hard drive on a file-by-file basis, sized in proportion to the size of the given file(s) & colorized according to type.

For someone it might be a new app idea. I'm hoping it already exists, however. I know a program like this wouldn't (need to) tell you the "path" to any files, but it would be nice to visualize which apps are hogging the most of the 16GB hard drive on my iPhone.

I'm aware of iTunes's simple Apps/Music/Video/Etc pie chart but am looking for something a bit more "WinDirStat/Disk Inventory X"-like.

Comment: It's definitely possible to make an app that does this, but whether or not Apple would allow it into the AppStore is a different issue. There have been other apps that do things like let you *view* the whole filesystem that have slipped past their system, but I've seen them all get taken down eventually.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson having answered this question, effectively, in a comment, do you suggest I close it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps there actually is an app that does what you're looking for (or something similar) that doesn't violate Apple's AppStore policies. It's hard to say what you'd search for in the AppStore to find such an app, but maybe somebody out there knows of one.

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to make a backup of the iOS device on a Mac/PC, then use a third party tool to copy the files into the filesystem as regular files.

From there you can run Disk Inventory X or any similar tool.

Beware that iOS uses compression and doesn't necessarily store all of your files on the local device (photos and music in particular could be in the cloud), so this will not give you an accurate measurement. But it will be as close as you can get.

Comment: Habe you tried this yourself?